# Retrieving Center from Rotated Rectangle

Tags: c++, opencv

How can I pull the `x` and `y` coordinates for a rotated rectangles center?

In the documentation it says that the Rotated Rectangle: "...

> returns a `Box2D` structure which contains following details:
>
> ( center (x,y), (width, height), angle of rotation )

I couldn't find anything out there on referencing the center, and I was unsuccessful in attempts to figure it out on my own.

Ultimately, I'm trying to pull the center points for each rotated rectangle to find clusters of similarly angled and nearby rectangles.

Comment: so `center(x,y)` is not what you need?

Comment: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.0/db/dd6/classcv_1_1RotatedRect.html RotatedRect.center is a Point2f. Where so you have this Box2D thing from?

Comment: @Micka Looks familiar... I think OP quoted it from the [Python contour features tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html), section 7b

Comment: Ah okay. I'm all sorts of confused, but I should have noticed I was in the wrong documentation. Thanks for the help! I think this is just evidence I'm getting a little ahead of myself with C++ and I should learn more fundamentals, because even with everyone's help I'm still having trouble figuring out how to call the center.

Answer (score 0):

According to [CvBox2D](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/old_basic_structures.html#cvbox2d):

> `struct CvBox2D` - Stores coordinates of a rotated rectangle.
>
> `CvPoint2D32f center`: Center of the box

So you need [CvPoint2D32f](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/old_basic_structures.html#cvpoint2d32f)

> `struct CvPoint2D32f` -
>   2D point with floating-point coordinates.
>
> `x`:  floating-point x-coordinate of the point.
>   `y`:  floating-point y-coordinate of the point.
>   `point`:  the point to convert.

to *access* the center's `x` and `y` by:

```
center.x // access rotated rectangle center's x
center.y // access rotated rectangle center's y
```